# Get html data attributes from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to send prodName and prodItem into a URL that will be captured by    product.html so when a user clicks on a product (index.html), a URL will be created and that URL will be used but on product.html. I want to catch prodName and proItem and put the text in the product.html but the value will be null.

**index.html**

```
$(".product-item").each(function(index, value) {
                var prodName = $(this).children("h2").attr("data-prodname");
                var prodItem = $(this).children("h2").attr("data-proditem");



                var link = $("<a href='product.html?prodName=" + prodName + "&prodItem=" + prodItem + "'/>");
                console.log(prodName);
                console.log(prodItem);
                $(this).children("img").wrap(link);
            });

        })
```

**product.html**

```
$.urlParam = function (parameterName) {
            var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + parameterName + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
            if (results === null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
            }
        }
        var adminSerial = $.urlParam('ProdName');
        var dashboardName = $.urlParam('ProdItem');

        $('#product').html("The text is " + adminSerial);
```

Comment: Please reduce the code relevant to the problem, refer to how to post a [mcve]

Comment: In index.html the URL is formed:     var link = $("<a href='product.html?prodName=" + prodName + "&prodItem=" + prodItem + "'/>");

Comment: var adminSerial = $.urlParam('ProdName');
is null in the product.html

Comment: Checkout your case string, in one side you use `prodName` and in other `ProdName`, they must match as are case sensitive.

Comment: Properly format question first

Answer (score 0):

*I put this code on pruduct.html and now it works.*

```
var getParams = function (url) {
        var params = {};
        var parser = document.createElement('a');
        parser.href = url;
        var query = parser.search.substring(1);
        var vars = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
            var pair = vars[i].split('=');
            params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
        return params;
    };
    var mylocation ={};
    var mylocation = getParams(window.location.href);
    console.log(mylocation.prodName);
    $('#product').html(mylocation.prodName);
    $('#item').html(mylocation.prodItem);
```